# How to join tables of different length in R/SQL?

Tags: sql, r

First table DailyOil with the fields DayofMonth, Month, Year, EXPL, AB,…

Second Table  HPower with the fields HourEnding, Day, Month, Year,  MWh1, MWh2, ….

I want to create a new table with HourEnding, Day, Month, Year,  MWh1, MWh2, EXPL, AB

Notice the second table as an addition time field so is 24 times long  than the oil table.

The R code:

```
Library(sqldf)
df4 <- sqldf("SELECT HP.Month, HP.Day, HP.Year, HP.Express_Avg, HP.Platte_Avg, HP.Full_Avg, HP.CasperToGurley_Avg, HP.OgallallatoEthlyn_Avg, OD.EXPL, OD.PLATTE, OD.CASPERtoGUERNSEY 
              FROM HPower HP 
              LEFT JOIN DailyOil OD 
              on HP.Day = OD.DayofMonth and HP.Month = OD.Month and HP.Year = OD.Year")

Error in sqliteExecStatement(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: near "FROM": syntax error)
```

Comment: Just a guess: what happens if you explicitly say `HPower AS HP`, and similarly for the other table?

Comment: I still get the same error with: df4 <- sqldf("SELECT HP.Month, HP.Day, HP.Year, HP.Express_Avg, HP.Platte_Avg, HP.Full_Avg, HP.CasperToGurley_Avg, HP.OgallallatoEthlyn_Avg, OD.EXPL, OD.PLATTE, OD.CASPERtoGUERNSEY
+       FROM HPower as HP LEFT JOIN DailyOil as OD 
+ on HP.Day = OD.DayofMonth and HP.Month = OD.Month and HP.Year = OD.Year")

Comment: sqldf uses sqlite and the [syntax for `SELECT`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) does use `AS`. Your second attempt in the comment looks better (apart from having stray `+` symbols). Did you get the same error message?

Comment: MAke the code in your question reproducible.  See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example   (Also sqlite does not require AS.)